# How to show the plot with correcaltions

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a data frame and I want to plot a figure like this. I try in R and python, but I can not. Can anybody help me to plot this data?
Thank you.
This is my simple data and code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 4, 5, 12, 5, 2,2], [-5, 8, 9, 0,2,1,8],[-6, 7, 11, 19,1,2,5],[-5, 1, 3, 7,5,2,5],[-5, 7, 3, 7,6,2,9],[2, 7, 9, 7,6,2,8]])
sns.pairplot(data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sns.pairplot()` is a simple function aimed at creating a pair-plot easily using the default settings. If you want more flexibility in terms of the kind of plots you want in the figure, then you have to use [`PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) directly

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1000,4)))

def remove_ax(*args, **kwargs):
    plt.axis('off')

g = sns.PairGrid(data=data)
g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_upper(remove_ax)
```

[image]